# Разрешить открывать EXE файл только один раз - Java

Tags: java

Я программирую приложения для компьютера на Java через программу Eclipse.

Как разрешить запускать EXE-файл приложения только один раз? То есть, если я запустил приложение, то, при повторном запуске, должно выходить сообщение об ошибке, что приложение уже запущено.

Comment: Непонятно о чём речь - вы хотите чтобы пользователи не запускали ваше приложение два раза или вы из своего приложения запускаете другие приложения и не хотите чтобы они запускались по два раза? P.S. exe и java вещи не совсем совместимые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут об этом http://rsdn.ru/forum/java/2194647.all Получилось у человека решить с помощью создания файла и попытки его удаления. Те если программа использует файл то удалить не получится на win а на nix использовали FileLock